# How to run server which runs through ng server or npm start as a daemon process?

Tags: node.js, angular, webserver

I have a demo application using angular 2. I usually run it through `npm start` and it runs. But, I want to run a server which is equivalent to whatever is running just like apache daemon process. Because when I run it through `npm start` or `npm start &` and close the terminal the server is also closed.

Comment: you need to look at pm2 - http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Comment: Does it run Angular 2 app?

Comment: Technically angular is just JavaScript that requires a small http server to be run in a browser.  npm start refers to the command run in your package.json file.  If that is ng serve, you are using cli  which is us using webpack, which runs its own server.  Bottom line is, develop  locally with open terminal running is normal. Pm2 or saas for production.

Comment: @Dylan I want to use it for production

Comment: How do you plan on serving the application?  If you have a host that supports it, you could use nginx within a docker container.

https://marcofranssen.nl/run-your-angular-app-in-a-nginx-docker-container/